# dplyr: remove values based on two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Using `df`

```
date <- c(rep(as.Date("2003-01-05"), 5), rep(as.Date("2004-01-05"), 5), rep(as.Date("2005-01-05"), 5), rep(as.Date("2006-01-05"), 5))
parameter <- rep(c("param_A", "param_B", "param_C", "param_D", "param_E"), 4)

df <- data.frame(date, parameter)
df$year <- year(df$date)
```

How can I remove `param_A` for `2003` but keep it for all other years?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can try with `filter`

```
df %>% 
    filter(!(parameter=="param_A" & year == 2003))
```